# Limit Bandwidth to GRPC application from within Golang

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I want to limit the amount of bandwidth my Go Client Uses. Is there a way to do this from inside the Go Program

This is tough to provide a code sample, but so far I've seen

1. Messing with the IPTables (sounds complicated for a client program to get right)
   https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34116/how-can-i-limit-the-bandwidth-used-by-a-process
2. DialOptions on Golang's GRPC Client but none seem related
   https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#DialOption
3. Wondershaper but I don't want my program to use other programs to work

Comment: Are you looking for a rate limiter to throttle the number of gRPC requests? Or throttling a single RPC that is streaming messages?

Comment: Throttling a single RPC that's sending messges. But not based on the number of requests its sending but based on the number of bytes

Comment: so you want to throttle a single connection, single RPC call,  streaming messages, correct?

Comment: yep totally that's it